# How to create a contacts directory in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013

anyone knows about a tutorial or similar to create a simple contacts directory (in spanish if you can :P )

Comment: Once you have some SP experience and know how to work with Search you can create one step-by-step following the blog: https://en.share-gate.com/blog/corporate-directory-sharepoint-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to All Site Content(`https://siteurl/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx`) > Add an app

Here find the Contacts list as below:

[image]

Create a list using this

The end result would be as below:

[image]

Comment: Ok, its fine, and what i need to do add the contacts view in the index page? (Srry im very new in this T_T) and finally what i need do to enable search?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a small contacts directory specific to a site you can use the contacts list template and create a list in the site. [Here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJnIPaqrfSAhXCHZQKHfK1BD8QtwIIGTAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dv4iPObhryGU&usg=AFQjCNHVCTHa3AjrNAArZsRB7Jz4836Fyw&sig2=EWxq3QzoJ2ghBfbi1S_P-Q&bvm=bv.148441817,d.dGo) is some guidance.

If your requirement is to create an organization wide directory, it involves a more complex approach. This [link](http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2013/05/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-people-directory/) might be helpful. In this approach, in a nutshell, all the user profiles in your SharePoint environment are crawled and indexed by the search engine. You use the search webpart and configure it to retrieve the people information from the index.